# How to use the type that returned by GetType in ObservableCollection<T>?

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I want to cast the `ItemSource` of a `WPF dataGrid` to an `ObservableCollection`,But i don't know the type of its elements,so i was thinking to get the type using this code:

```
 var returnedType = dg.ItemsSource.AsQueryable().ElementType;
```

And use the returnedType here:

```
var sourceCollection = (ObservableCollection<???>)dg.ItemsSource;
```

To be more clear i want to cast it into `ObservableCollection` because i need to use its`CollectionChanged`.And i can't use generic types here because  i want to use it in a customizad `DataGrid`.

Comment: The question is absurd. If you don't know item type in compile-time, how are you going to work with instances of that unknown type in code? I mean, what are you going to write after the dot in this line: `sourceCollection[0].`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with WPF, but I don't think you can cast whole collections like that. You could try using `Cast<>` extension method.

Comment: @Tarec It depends on whether the `ItemsSource` already is an `ObservableCollection<T>`. If it is, then casting to the type it already has is fine. (But as Dennis noted, if you don't know `T` at compile time, the cast, even if it were possible, would be useless.)  If it isn't, then you're right, the cast would throw an exception. I do suspect the latter is the case.

Comment: @Dennis if you have a method that accepts an ObservableCollection<T> then it wouldn't be that absurd because the method would know how to deal with it.

Comment: @RuneFS: the method will be called via reflection in this case. Hence, there's enough to construct collection type dynamically, using reflection too. At the same time, OP shows the sample, when the type must be known statically.

Comment: @ Dennis:It's not that absurd.I want to cast it to an ObservableCollection in order to use its CollectionChanged event.And i want to do this in the datagrid.loaded method(i customized the datagrid,so i cant use generic types here),its why i don't know the type in compile-time!

Comment: @raha: then you don't need to cast it to `OnservableCollection<T>`. You just need to cast it to `INotifyCoollectionChanged`. See Knaģis's answer.

Comment: @Dennis:Yes thank you,i saw it and made it as answer.Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Dennis no it wouldn't require reflection. If it had been for calling a method with an parameter of type ObserveableCollection<T> then dynamic would suffice. There's not enough information in the question to support your claim that the type must be known statically since there's no information on how sourceCollection is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ObservableCollection<T>` implements the [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface and the event you need is defined on this interface. So you can write the code like this:

```
var sourceCollection = (INotifyCollectionChanged)dg.ItemsSource;
sourceCollection.CollectionChanged += ... your delegate here ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`ObservableCollection<>` is derived from [Collection<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so you can cast it to `IList` or `ICollection` and access the collection that way. However, you'll have to treat the items in the collection as `object`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an interface for the type and have your runtime types implement that interface.

Comment: You implement an interface compile time

Comment: that is what i meant actually. The runtime types must be castable to that interface.

Answer (score 0):

A downcast is a compile time construct letting the compile know that you know more that the compile does about the runtime type of the object. If you don't know the type at compile time you can't use a cast.

However if you don't know the actual type you won't be able to do much with it later on anyways. How would you access a property of an object of an unknown type?

In general there'd be two different ways of handling issues with unknown types where they have some commonalities one would be the dynamic language runtime

```
dynamic sourceCollection = dg.ItemsSource;
```

You can use this if you know that all objects will have e.g. a `Value` property but that they do not share a common base type declaring that property.

```
sourceCollection.Value
```

would in that case be legal (and work as long as the constraint is not violated)

or maybe more often you'd be able to pass sourceCollection to a method that accepts an `ObservableCollaction<T>` as an argument

Alternatively you can use generics

```
public ObservableCollection<T> GetSourceCollection(DataGrid dg) {
    (ObservableCollection<T>)dg.ItemsSource
}
```

This only defers the issue of not knowing the type to somewhere else in your code but you should know the type of collection at some point and you will often be able to push the issue until that point.

Answer (score 0):

Although, its not clear what you need, and what would be generics of any use if you don't know the type or an abstraction of it at compile time.
Here is a way :

```
var returnedType = dg.ItemsSource.AsQueryable().ElementType;
Type generic = typeof(ObservableCollection<>);    
Type specific = generic.MakeGenericType(typeof(returnedType));    
ConstructorInfo ci = specific.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);    
object o = ci.Invoke(new object[] { });
```

the object `o` is your `ObservableCollection<returnedType >`.

And if you need to invoke any methods of the ObservableCollections upon it, you are going to need reflection to do so.

Comment: reference types are not boxed